# Is it possible to pass value of a Variable from Testng.xml file?

Tags: rest, automated-tests, testng, testng-dataprovider

Here is my code

```
public class Environment {

    public static String baseURL;

    public static String setURL(String paramSet) {

        /*
        @BeforeSuite
     @Parameters("env")
         */

        if (paramSet.equalsIgnoreCase("Production")) {
            baseURL = Constants.prodBase;

        } else if (paramSet.equalsIgnoreCase("Staging")) {
            baseURL = Constants.stagingBase;
        }
        return baseURL;
    }

    public static void getURL() {
        RestAssured.baseURI = setURL("Production");
    }
}
```

In the method `getURL()` i want to pass the parameter in the method `setURL(myvariable)` having value as `Staging/Production` from TestNG.xml file. I know i can pass it as parameters but this function `getURL()` will be called in each test and requirement is not to pass a parameter in every method for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
Parameters({ "env-param" })
@BeforeSuite
public void prameterTestOne(String env) {
    System.out.println("Test one suite param is: " + env);
}
```

XML file

```
<suite name="Parameter test Suite" verbose="1">
<!-- This parameter will be passed to every test in this suite -->
<parameter name="suite-param" value="Production / Staging" />
<test name="Parameter Test one">
    <classes>
        <class name="someClassName"> 
        </class>
    </classes>
</test>
```

Comment: This would go in the method parameter. I want to pass as a variable.

Comment: Yes this will go as a parameter, if you want to get it as a value, then write a wrapper which will take this param value from that paramter at suitelevel @BeforeSuite and write a getter for the same . Or  pass the param value as an env variable and get in your code anywhere by using System.getProperty("pass your env variable name"), i preffered the later one u dont have to touch the code again and again for changing the en value [i mean if using Jenkin you can pass it as a env variable or if running on Eclipse you can define the varaible  in Run Configurations under Environment section]

Comment: can you help with the code for latter one? exactly what i am looking . Thanks!

Comment: i updated the comment ...where i have mentioned just Right click on you test file or project , Select Run Configurations and click on Environment , click on New , give your env name and value and in code use System.getProperty("pass the env name").